# Codeigniter Dynamic Page Title not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I looked around and found some threads that mentioned this, but for some reason when I add my page title to Public_Controller, which extends MY_Controller it does not work. If I don't add a page title to my other controllers that extend Public_Controller, then their page titles should be "Test Title". However, that is not the case. Here is what I have

Public_Controller.php:

```
class Public_Controller extends MY_Controller
{
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->data['pageTitle'] = 'Test Title'; // pages without a title should display this
    ....
}

}
```

Home.php (my default controller...extends Public_Controller):

```
class Home extends Public_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent:: __construct();
}

function index()
{ 
   $this->data['pageTitle'] = 'Your page title';

   $data['main_content'] = 'home';

   // My header which contains the <title> is in the template
   $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}

}
```

The above works if I do this as it should, but I want pages to display a title if they don't have this set:

```
$data['pageTitle'] = 'Your page title';
```

Header area:

```
<title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?> </title>
```

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Where $data property is defined? Try define public $data = array(); in Public_Controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want you can do this:

```
<title><?php echo (isset($pageTitle)) ? $pageTitle : 'Default title text'; ?> </title>
```

This way if a title is not set it will output the default value.

Comment: what if you want the title to be dynamic. for example the title of a profile. how to set title when you have to show it through modal? @cryptic

Answer (score 3):

do it like this-

```
$data['pageTitle'] = 'Your page title';
```

instead

```
$this->data['pageTitle'] = 'Your page title';
```

Comment: It doesn't work when I do that in Public_Controller. It does work if I do it in the home controller though. However, I want to be abel to use the Public_Controller title for pages that I don't manually set like I would in the Home

Comment: @KraigBalla did you make this change in both files? Because it should work.

Comment: @KraigBalla: store your default title in sesssion and before you print the title just chk that $pageTitle is set. If it set than print $pageTitle else session value.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi session should not be used for such an action. The code just needs to be correctly done to set the title. Your code would work, I just don't think OP did the change in both the files as your example says 'Your page title' so OP may have just changed that line.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi So that would be the only way in order to get the Public_Controller to work?

Comment: if you want you can do this: `<title><?php echo (isset($pageTitle)) ? $pageTitle : 'Default title text'; ?> </title>`

Comment: @cryptic When I change it in the Home controller, yes it works. However, if I didn't set a page title manually the Public_Controller should display it's page title. I've tried both in that controller and it doesn't work.

Comment: @KraigBalla please see above comment, if the title is not set it will echo out a default title.

Comment: @cryptic what you posted does work...just wanted to try and use my core controller. If it's not possible then your way works too. Add and answer and I'll accept and bump.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21747/discussion-between-cryptic-and-kraigballa)

Comment: @KraigBalla with your original code you can access the value from the parent class in `Home` using `parent::$data['pageTitle'];`